# In Graph Algorithm, what is the best way to determine if a node is visited?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I was initially doing it in two ways. One way is by storing visited nodes in a list and traversing the list to determine if a node has been visited before. Another was using a boolean array which keeps track of both visited and unvisited nodes. It really interested me, what is the best way?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand, but probably a boolean array/bitfield if all nodes have an index.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? The solution using the least memory or the one which has the fastest lookups?

Comment: Why all the votes to close? The question seems eminently appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: Why closed? He might need to specify what kind of best he is looking for. But this question is still valuable and practical for many people?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach, which can be useful for micro-optimization (better cache behavior, avoids lookup), is storing a flag on each node object. The obvious drawback is that the graph algorithms are not re-entrant. Want to do a *different* graph traversal to make a decision during traversal? Well, you can't. You also have to remember to clear all these flags afterwards.

The other category is maintaining a separate data structure on a per-traversal basis. Both of the approaches you give fall under this, although the list approach is very inefficient -- O(n) time for every lookup. The boolean array (possibly compressed into a bitset; this option is *extremely* space efficient) is simple and efficient in both time and space, but requires that the nodes have consecutive indices/ids. This is not always given, and has consequences for other parts of the graph handling.

If you don't have that, and instead refer to graph objects with pointers, you can use a mapping based on that. In higher-level languages, such as Python, this is very simple (and due to highly tuned hash table/set data structures, rather efficient too).

The obvious advantage is that graph traversals are re-entrant. While this may not sound like much, I can attest that situations where this is useful do arise at times.

Comment: I'd also mention that an intrusive traveral algorithm just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @MooingDuck I feel the same way, but I prefer giving reasons over a gut feeling. Also, there may be cases where it's more natural, though I don't know any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your usage, 
For better time performance, you can use hash maps
You could also use a b-tree to store the nodes O(logn) insertion and lookup

Personally, I would use a hash map, based on a unique value for each node. You can control the size of the hashmap to reflect your needs and with a good hashing function, collisions can be controlled. Look at this code for an example https://github.com/himanshujindal/Reconstructing-Books-from-Google-Ngrams